# Django ORM query for empty FileFields

Tags: python, django, orm

It's not clear to me whether this is possible through the ORM - it doesn't appear so, but maybe I'm missing something?

```
   class ApplicationInstitution(models.Model):
       ...
       transcript_file = FileField(upload_to=...)
```

Some of those `ApplicationInstitution` objects may already have had a `transcript_file` uploaded into them, while others have not. I want to query for instances with an empty FileField. At first I thought I could so something like

`ApplicationInstitution.objects.filter(transcript_file__isnull=False)`

or similar, but this gives unexpected results (either all records or zero, depending on whether you use `filter` or `exclude`). And if you try to access the actual file object, you get a Raise, not an empty:

```
>>> a.institutions.last().transcript_file.file
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: The 'transcript_file' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

I've written a model method using try/except that gets me the answer, but ORM would be cleaner. Is a query for empty or non-empty FileFields even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query for empty strings:

```
# instances with empty FileField
ApplicationInstitution.objects.filter(transcript_file='')
# and with a file already uploaded
ApplicationInstitution.objects.exclude(transcript_file='')
```

Comment: You're totally right - it didn't occur to me that those pointers were just strings. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
transcript_file = FileField(upload_to=..., null=True)
```

and try this for `ApplicationInstitution` without file:

```
ApplicationInstitution.objects.filter(transcript_file__isnull=True)
```

for `ApplicationInstitution` with file:

```
ApplicationInstitution.objects.exclude(transcript_file__isnull=True)
```

Comment: FileField is a string-based field; you shouldn't use NULL on such fields, as empty values will always be stored as empty strings, not as NULLs. This will lead to two different values meaning 'no data'. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#null).

Comment: As noted in the question, attempting to use `is_null=True` on this query crashes the ORM.

Comment: @rafalmp thanks for the correction, i didn't know that filefield is a string-based field,  shacker is 'isnull' not 'is_null'

Comment: You're right about `isnull` rather than `is_null` - I've edited the question. But if I change it, I get unexpected results rather than an ORM crash. Treating as a string is  the right way to go here.